# htaccess config : using part of the URL as parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I'm using a URL shortener and i'd like to have the following :

from http://domain.com/ld541as2 redirecting to http://www.newsite.com/login-ld541as2.html

There are a lot of possible URL but i'm guessing it's possible to do it with 1 rule ?

Any chance any of you guys know how to do so ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /login-$1.html [L,R]
```

**PS:** If you don't want full (external) redirection then remove `R` flag from above rule.